# Calculation with a lot of columns from a lot of dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to do some operations between some columns of different data frames, i had tried that with the follow code:

```
df_swap['Apropriacao'] = df_sw[(df_sw.loc[:, 'Ativo'] == df_mov.loc[:, 'Ativo']).all() and (df_sw.loc[:, 'Data posicao'] == df_mov.loc[:, 'Data posicao']).all()].sum(axis=1)
```

But I believe that is not the right way to do it (and show a exception).

The sample of dataframe are:

**df_mov**

```
idx Data posicao   Ativo   Valor
0    2017-07-03    RXU7     0.0
1    2017-07-04    RXU7     0.0
2    2017-07-05    RXU7     0.0
3    2017-07-06    RXU7     0.0
4    2017-07-07    RXU7     0.0
5    2017-07-10    RXU7     0.0
...
21   2017-07-03    GCQ7     0.0
22   2017-07-04    GCQ7     0.0
23   2017-07-05    GCQ7     0.0
24   2017-07-06    GCQ7     0.0
25   2017-07-07    GCQ7  1341.0
26   2017-07-10    GCQ7     0.0
...
42   2017-07-03  CNHBRL     0.0
43   2017-07-04  CNHBRL     0.0
44   2017-07-05  CNHBRL     0.0
45   2017-07-06  CNHBRL     0.0
46   2017-07-07  CNHBRL     0.0
47   2017-07-10  CNHBRL     0.0
...
```

**df_sw**

```
   Data posicao   Ativo Data vencimento  Apropriacao
0    2017-07-03    RXU7      2017-09-07      -1431.17
1    2017-07-04    RXU7      2017-09-07    -788258.59
2    2017-07-05    RXU7      2017-09-07      -4206.24
3    2017-07-06    RXU7      2017-09-07      50062.78
4    2017-07-07    RXU7      2017-09-07     499642.57
5    2017-07-10    RXU7      2017-09-07      49191.00
...
21   2017-07-03    GCQ7            None          0.00
22   2017-07-04    GCQ7      2017-07-31       1820.06
23   2017-07-05    GCQ7      2017-07-31      -2767.20
24   2017-07-06    GCQ7      2017-07-31      -1648.37
25   2017-07-07    GCQ7      2017-07-31          0.00
26   2017-07-10    GCQ7            None          0.00
...
42   2017-07-03  CNHBRL            None          0.00
43   2017-07-04  CNHBRL            None          0.00
44   2017-07-05  CNHBRL            None          0.00
45   2017-07-06  CNHBRL            None          0.00
46   2017-07-07  CNHBRL            None          0.00
47   2017-07-10  CNHBRL            None          0.00
```

How can i sum `df_mov['Valor']` with `df_sw['Apropriacao']` where `df_mov['Data posicao']` is equal to `df_sw['Data posicao']` and `df_mov['Ativo']` is equal to `df_sw['Ativo']`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can i sum df_mov['Valor'] with df_sw['Apropriacao'] where df_mov['Data posicao'] is equal to df_sw['Data posicao'] and df_mov['Ativo'] is equal to df_sw['Ativo']?

Comment: why not `merge` or join two df to one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest merging the dataframes and then performing the summation on the columns (this assumes you're trying to sum the values for each row, rather than sum the columns as a whole):

```
df_mov.merge(df_sw, 
    left_on=['Data posicao', 'Ativo'], 
    right_on=['Data posicao', 'Ativo'],
    )[['Valor', 'Apropricao']].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Yes, the goal is to perform the sum per line, but as long as the two dates and the two assets (of each data frame) are equal.